# how to clear localstorage,sessionStorage and cookies in javascript? and then retrieve?

Tags: javascript

How to completely clear `localstorage`, `sessionStorage` and `cookies` in javascript ?

Is there any way one can get these values back after clearing them ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. and i want to know is there any way to get a value after clear the value

Comment: @dystroy I disagree, it could be encapsulated as 'how to wipe all client storage'.

Answer (score 189):

> *how to completely clear localstorage*

```
localStorage.clear();
```

> *how to completely clear sessionstorage*

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

> *[...] Cookies ?*

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
    var myCookie = cookies[i];
    var pos = myCookie.indexOf("=");
    var name = pos > -1 ? myCookie.substr(0, pos) : myCookie;
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
}
```

> *is there any way to get the value back after clear these ?*

**No**, there isn't. But you shouldn't rely on this if this is related to a security question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve localStorage, sessionStorage or cookie values via javascript in the browser after they've been deleted via javascript.

If what you're really asking is if there is some other way (from outside the browser) to recover that data, that's a different question and the answer will entirely depend upon the specific browser and how it implements the storage of each of those types of data.

For example, Firefox stores cookies as individual files.  When a cookie is deleted, its file is deleted.  That means that the cookie can no longer be accessed via the browser.  But, we know that from outside the browser, using system tools, the contents of deleted files can sometimes be retrieved.

If you wanted to look into this further, you'd have to discover how each browser stores each data type on each platform of interest and then explore if that type of storage has any recovery strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The standard [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-localstorage),
does not say anything about the restoring any of these.
So there won't be any standard way to do it. You have to go through the way the browsers
implement these, or find a way to backup these before you delete them.