# How to clear localStorage in IE10 & IE11 from developer tool?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage

I opened `IE11` developer tool it has lot of options , but i cant find how can I the clear `localStorage` data. ?

is there something like this in IE11 ?

[image]

Will clear cache data does not clear `localStorage` or  `sessionStorage` data ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try to type this in the JavaScript console

```
localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear();
```

I think this is the most straightforward way to do this. I don't see any option that explicitly affects localStorage and/or sessionStorage in developer tools (at least nothing that looks like the Resources view in Dev Tools in Chrome).

**EDIT2** In Microsoft Edge, there is a way to see/clear `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` and `cookies` through the GUI.

- Open the Dev Tools (F12)
- Go to Debugger View
- Open the `localStorage` tab (click the folder icon or `Ctrl+O`, select `localStorage`)
- Select all and delete (through right clicking, or `Ctrl-A` + `Del`)

Comment: The UI may have changed since - to open the localStorage / cookies etc tabs on Edge / IE 11, click the folder icon in your debugger view.

Answer (score 9):

Try `localStorage.clear()` and `sessionStorage.clear()` in Console panel of IE Developer toolbar. It returns an `"undefined"` but seems to clear local storage and session storage.

For more :
**[How to clear localstorage, sessionStorage and cookies in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804874)**

Comment: it returns undefined because clear does not return anything, hence undefined.

Answer (score 6):

**Try this:**

```
window.localStorage.clear();
window.sessionStorage.clear();
```