# How to clear localstorage in IE11?

Tags: html, local-storage

I want to clear local storage in IE11, I know in previous versions we have network tab, there we can select local storage and delete objects, but in IE 11 i can only see localstorage objects from console of IE11, but i am not able to clear those using "localstorage.clear()"

Please let me know how to delete local cache in IE11

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20610029/1028949

Comment: I have already tried as per above said link, but it does not work. I have tried to clear in console using localStorage.clear(); also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling 
    `localStorage.clear();` and/or 
    `sessionStorage.clear();`

in the console of IE Developer Tools (you can hit the F12 key to open the Developer Tools) then look for the 'Console' tab, then run those javascript function calls there.

Comment: thanks, it worked, but in few IE 11 browsers, i had to use localStorage.removeItem('key'); since localStorage.clear(); returns undefined.

Comment: localStorage.clear() has no return value, ergo undefined. The local storage will still have been cleared though, as a simple call to localStorage will show.