# Flask Spotify API Logging out function

Tags: python, api, authentication, flask, access-token

I have a small Flask app which allows Spotify users to authenticate themselves onto a home page. The logging in and access to tokens etc works fine and are as follows. I get a http 302 response for `/spotify_authentication` view point and it redirects me to `/spotify` correctly.

```
#  Client Keys
CLIENT_ID = "##"
CLIENT_SECRET = "##"

# Spotify URLS
SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
SPOTIFY_API_BASE_URL = "https://api.spotify.com"
API_VERSION = "v1"
SPOTIFY_API_URL = "{}/{}".format(SPOTIFY_API_BASE_URL, API_VERSION)

CLIENT_SIDE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/spotify"
REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/spotify"

SCOPE = 'user-read-private user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state user-library-read'
STATE = ""
SHOW_DIALOG_bool = True
SHOW_DIALOG_str = str(SHOW_DIALOG_bool).lower()

auth_query_parameters = {
    "response_type": "code",
    "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
    "scope": SCOPE,
    "client_id": CLIENT_ID
}


@app.route('/spotify_authentication')
def spotify_auth():
    url_args = "&".join(["{}={}".format(key,urllib.parse.quote(val)) for key, val in auth_query_parameters.items()])
    auth_url = "{}/?{}".format(SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL, url_args)

    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/spotify')
def spotify():
    auth_token = request.args['code']
    code_payload = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": str(auth_token),
        "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
    }

    base64encoded = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).encode())
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(base64encoded.decode())}
    post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload, headers=headers)

    response_data = json.loads(post_request.text)
    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
    refresh_token = response_data["refresh_token"]
    token_type = response_data["token_type"]
    expires_in = response_data["expires_in"]

    authorization_header = {"Authorization":"Bearer {}".format(access_token)}

    return render_template('spotify.html')
```

Now I want to implement a logout button which terminates the authentication. There doesn't seem to be many useful answers online. Some guide you to redirect a `/logout` view point to another page. When I do that, I am able to go back in the web browser to my authenticated page - which doesn't mean logging out to me! For example, directing to `accounts.spotify.com/logout` redirects me to Spotify's own logging out page to log me out of their platform, not my app.

How do I implement a logout method which wipes the authentication access and redirects to `/spotify_authentication` correctly using Python 3? I don't mind if the user has to authenticate again with their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that you just have to clear the session variables which contains access token

Comment: So I should set ```access_token = ' ' ``` on a new logout view point?

Comment: I don't quite see it but I believe you have the frontend codes that is using the access_token, and I assume that you store it frontend as session variable, if this is the case you need to clear it from browser. Can do this `session.clear()` from flask or with JavaScript check [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804874/3210415)

Comment: I'm not using any sessions. How do you generate a session from auth?

Comment: Can you also post your frontend code `spotify.html`. This part is sending data to webbrowser `def spotify()` last part of it

Comment: ```spotify.html``` is currently empty! I've not started parsing any data to the frontend yet. But the authentication etc appears in the search bar with the token etc.