# flask clear session on click on the home link

Tags: python, flask

I want to clear the session if someone clicks on the Home button or Site name.

Home Link:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" ><h1>Home</h1></a>
```

I tried this

```
<a href="{{ session.clear(); url_for('index') }}" ><h1>Home</h1></a>
```

But this errored out.

Is there any way to include the session clear in this jinja2 template for the home link?

Comment: session.clear needs to be called from the backend (eg in your /home route)

Comment: @JoranBeasley The Home page contains a form which heavily depends on the session. There is no condition i can come up with based on which I can clear the session in /home route.

Comment: By session if you mean sessionStorage of the browser - this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804462/how-to-clear-localstorage-sessionstorage-and-cookies-in-javascript-and-then-ret

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route. Example:

```
@app.route('/index')
def signout():
    if 'usersLogged' in session:
        session.pop('usersLogged', None)
        return redirect(url_for('bla-bla-URL'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('bla-bla-URL'))
```

You should not use an index page for this. Name it for example 'signout'

Comment: There is no signin or signout concept. And whatever else names I put to the route, the home link will basically show that link instead of just the site link. like instead of `/` or `/index`, now it'll show `/whatever`. I get it, it'll redirect to the required page. Still it's kind of misleading.